# Creating a daily Search Query for the previous day to today

Tags: query, date

I am trying to make a custom search query in maximo for equipment at work. I have a specific time range I want but it is always for the day before. Example: Today is 8/26/2021. I want a query for 8/25/2021 at 5:30am to 8/26/2021 at 2:30am. This is for every day so the 27th means I need from the 26 to the 27 and so on.

Below is how it appears when I do it manually for the day.

```
(reportdate <= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-08-24 06:30:00.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')  
and persongroup = 'LF WES MAINT' and siteid = 'ARD-WES' 
and reportdate >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('2021-08-23 09:30:00.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp related queries are SQL dialect dependent in most cases. Looks like you are using Oracle, so for it:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - 1 + INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE from_,
    TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '02:30' HOUR TO MINUTE to_
FROM dual;
```

First you remove time from current timestamp using `TRUNC` function, then subtract number of days if needed and then add time interval to the truncated date.

If we incorporate those into your condition set, it will look like this:

```
(reportdate <= TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '02:30' HOUR TO MINUTE
and persongroup = 'LF WES MAINT' and siteid = 'ARD-WES' 
and reportdate >= TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - 1 + INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE)
```